# Using Sliced Banner in Wordpress

Tags: css, image, wordpress, slice

I am much confused that how can use a sliced banner in `Wordpress`. I have a psd file and have done some slicing and added a few links on it. The psd is for banner image in header. When i save it for web, it divides the psd file to sliced peices.
The problem is, Wordpress Allows single image as banner, How can I use slice psd file as banner

sorry for bad english or quality of question. Although i am at trouble while thinking and doing about it..

Guide me Please

Comment: This might help http://voodoopress.com/customizing-twentyeleven-lets-start-with-width-and-smaller-header/

Comment: I am using twenty eleven 1.3 and link to my site is http://www.klusdesign.com/blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not too difficult.

You can create separate  containers for each part of the header image inside the header.php file.

Give them each an id or a class so you can style them with CSS in your style sheet.

That way you can position them individually and control where your links are.

If you are new to CSS or altering wordpress, this is a good time to learn.

For this project you will need to understand absolute positioning, relative positioning,
z-index, background-image property, img element, and the CSS box model for your divs.

These are concepts you can learn quickly. The CSS cookbook is a good reference to work with.

MOST IMPORTANT: make a back-up copy of your theme and database before you start changing things. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you would have to either hard code the header image in the header.php file or face not having the ability to have custom links.

As you have identified, Wordpress does not allow multiple images as a header image and would require custom HTML & CSS undoubtedly

Comment: can you give me some hints for header.php hardcoding? i can atleast give it a try

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to your Wordpress Site, I will then be able to better advise from there!